# Is private token-free blockchains valid solution for one-off services?

Tags: blockchain

We have a customer who thinks that blockchains might help solve his industry-specific problem. To avoid disclosing the business idea, I'll have to be abstract here and use an analogy from healthcare industry, which has very similar specifics. Disclaimer: I'm very new to blockchains, so feel free to correct me.

Let's imagine, there exists a drug to treat some specific kind of seizures that might occur for some people.

This drug can be prescribed only by certified companies.

The customer must receive only one dosage of the drug each time he/she has a seizure.

Let's assume that the distribution of the drug is perfect and there are no ways to steal the drug or illegally buy it.

The main problem to solve for the industry is to make sure that a person does not abuse the system and receives only one prescription for one event of seizure. Here is how a customer currently can cheat:

- a customer has a seizure, goes to the local branch office of the imaginary company and asks for a prescription. The company does some medical tests and issues the prescription, keeping the record in the local database
- the customer quickly travels to another company (maybe in another country) and again asks for a prescription. This company has no access to the data of the other companies and cannot find out if the customer has or has not already received a prescription elsewhere for this event of seizure. So, this company issues a new prescription again.

Now the customer has received two prescriptions for a single event of seizure. That's abuse of the system.

Private blockchains might solve the issue. But I have some doubts here:

1. I'm not sure how new customer registration could be synchronized across the companies. If a record for this customer already exists in the distributed database, the operator should not create a new record. I doubt that a single block per customer would work because of the following points below. Do we need a blockchain of blockchains - that is, a master blockchain that gets updated with blocks to point to a new customer specific private blockchain each time a new customer joins our "drug prescription system"?
2. We want to keep entire history of the customer's seizures and received prescriptions. We never change existing records - they should be immutable. We just add new records to the customer's private "history chain". If we for some reason (error in medical tests etc.) want to cancel a previously issued prescription, we create a new record with information about the cancellation and the seizure timestamp for which the prescription has been cancelled.
3. Given access to customer's data, we want to be able to decode it all at once and then browse the records, filter them by date etc. But we might want to also collect some statistical data about all customers and their prescriptions. How do we implement searching, calculating etc. on a blockchain, if each customer's data has to be decrypted with a separate key? I guess, blockchains cannot be searched and filtered the same way as good old relational SQL databases, right? Does that mean we need some other parallel blockchain where we record and sync all the statistical data of interest? How to ensure transactions over multiple blockchains?
4. As I understand, usually block changes are possible only with private keys. But here we have two kinds of access requirements:

   - a customer should be able to read his own records only but does not have permissions to write any changes (no prescribing drugs to himself). So, he needs some kind of read-only-access key.
   - the company (and all of its local branches and partners in different countries) need to have read-add (not write - no actual modification of history) access for this customer. A customer cannot register himself but has to do it through the company. The company is the issuer of the keys and the holder of the "add records key".

How to ensure that these keys are distributed through the network of the companies and do not leak outside? Of course, we can give the "public key" to the customer so he/she can read own records, but even this key is not entirely "public" per se - a customer should not access other customers' records.

5. How fast is blockchain distribution and how to resolve conflicts? If user has enough time to request two prescriptions in different companies, let's say, in 1 minute time, how do we ensure that only the first request is passed through and the second one gets rejected?
6. We want to record events in two sequences

   - for each customer separately - his private history, accessible only to himself and companies
   - history of all prescriptions issued by the companies in our network

Does this again mean that we need two blockchains or is it possible to somehow create a single chain where all history records of the entire network are stored but every customer can access and decrypt only the records of his own history?

7. Which of the most popular enterprise level blockchain services and products (if any at all) might be the most appropriate for this case - Hyperledger, IBM Bluemix, Microsoft Coco, Etherium, Rubix by Deloitte?
8. And finally, it seems all the problem boils down to the need of a central authority that would keep the registry of all prescriptions and customers. These companies are competitors and none of them wants to maintain the central database nor involve some neutral 3rd party company and pay for its services. Still, it's not clear if the blockchain (or maybe it would be more correct to call it just distributed ledger) will be the right solution because someone still has to establish and maintain the list of trusted companies. They definitely won't agree to use proof-of-work (mining) to ensure blockchain integrity, so again a central authority will be required anyway. But maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here I try to answer your questions. However, I think that you have very clear what you want and now, you have to take some time to develop the Smart Contract.

I think that the [Hyperledger Fabric](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/) will be a great solution for you.

Answers:

1. You don't need to registry each customer more than once. Then, for example with the ID of a customer, you would consult the history of that customer.
2. Blockchain gives the chance to it.
3. Some Blockchain save the state of the ledger (ledger=all the infor that it is in the Blockchain) in a parallel DB, to facilitate the users consulting the info. In Hyperledger you can define a CouchDB.
4. It dependes on how will you develop your Smart Contract.
5. Hyperledger Fabric uses the PBFT algorithm for consensus. It generates a block in 10 seconds, so after that time your information will be *"online"*.
6. Probably you should create two different channels. A channel is like a Blockchain that you create inside your network.
7. Hyperledger. I don't know very much about some of the others.
8. The companies should reach a consensus.